# Get working Ionic + ngCordova + background geolocation

Tags: ios, angularjs, geolocation, ionic-framework, ngcordova

**Goal of the app:** get geolocation on each move and log location either when app is in foreground and background.

I've tried so many code and combination but I can't manage to have it working (2 days from now...).

The classic geolocation (getCurrentPosition) is working fine but when we close the app the background geolocation is launched but nothing happen... Function "callbackFn" is never fired.

I'm testing on IOS with xcode > Capabilities Audio & location activated for background activity. I also made working the jQuery sample example given in plugin so I saw it working but never with ionic/angularjs.

Here is the current controller handling the background:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $ionicPlatform, $window)
{
$scope.lat_geo = "loading lat...";
$scope.long_geo = "loading long...";


//-- Geolocal launch
var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy : false,
    desiredAccuracy: 0,
    stationaryRadius: 1,
    distanceFilter: 5,
    notificationTitle: 'Background tracking', // <-- android only, customize the title of the notification
    notificationText: 'ENABLED', // <-- android only, customize the text of the notification
    activityType: 'AutomotiveNavigation',
    debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false // <-- enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
};

$ionicPlatform.ready(function()
{
    console.log("[IONIC PLATFORM IS NOW READY]");

    //-- First launch a basic geolocalisation to get user acceptance of geosharing ;)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
            console.log('[GEOLOCAL JS1] Location from Phonegap');
    },
    function (error){
            console.log('[GEOLOCAL JS1] error with GPS: error.code: ' + error.code + ' Message: ' + error.message);
    },options);

    //-- test adaptation depuis l'app jquery
    var callbackFn = function(location) {
            console.log('[BackgroundGeoLocation] Update callback:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
    };

    var failureFn = function(error) {
            console.log('[BackgroundGeoLocation] Error: '+error);
    };

    $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, options);

    // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.  The user will be tracked whenever they suspend the app.
    $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation.start();

    //-- Just a timeout to retreive long / lat
    $timeout(function()
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location)
        {
            console.log('[GEOLOCAL JS3] Location from Phonegap');
            startPos = location;
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.lat_geo = startPos.coords.latitude;
                $scope.long_geo = startPos.coords.longitude;
            });
            console.log("[GEOLOCAL BASIC] OK this time :)");
        },
        function (error){
            console.log('[GEOLOCAL JS3] error with GPS: error.code: ' + error.code + ' Message: ' + error.message);
        },options);
    }, 3000);

});
//-- End Geolocal
})
```

I've put all my code (a complete ionic app starter) on github: https://github.com/Jeff86/ionic_ngcordova_backgroundgeo_test/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I read this article http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/backgroundGeolocation/

I see that you should put your code into

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { ... });`

Do you find any solution?

Comment: Hi, I did tried to encapsulate with deviceready but didn't made the trick. You can see on controller.js that I put it in comment on line 70. For now I just gave up to use this bglocation as I don't have time to spend on it, maybe in few months.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to use the std Cordova-geolocation plugin in the bg, it'll kill the battery in no time.

I'm the author of the underlying background-geolocation plugin for Ionic.  I've created a New Ionic-based SampleApp.

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-SampleApp

Comment: RTFM, that's clearly documented.  That Android version is no longer supported, btw.  It eats the battery like ants at a picnic.  I don't recommend that for a production app, especially if you want your users to like you.

Comment: yes, I found it. It would be kinda nice though, if you state the things that do not work at all for a platform, in the code sample. Instead of writing at lengths about it, and mentioning in the last chapter in `behavior` that something actually does not work at all. 
Anyway I need to check the location only every, say, 30 minutes.

Comment: The version you're using is no longer supported (and hasn't been for at least 6 months).  The new repo is here https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

Comment: If you have further issues, you'll be better served raising issues directly at the repo.